# Adding foreign key to model using chicagoboss?

Tags: erlang, chicagoboss

I am a newbie to erlang and chicago boss. I followed Chicago boss API documentation. I have been working with Python and Django earlier. Now in Chicago boss can we add foreign key in models.

This is my model.

**model**:    anatomy.erl

```
-module(anatomy, [Id,
                 UID,
                 Name,
                 Property,
                 Ratio::float(),
                 Value::integer(),
                 Pieces::float(),
                 Status]).
-compile(export_all).
```

There is another model.

**model**: species.erl

```
-module(species, [Id,
                 UID,
                 Name,
                 Property,
                 Anatomy,
                 Morphology   
                 Gender]).
-compile(export_all).
```

I have to add `Anatomy` as a foreign key in `species` table.

Comment: @which database are you using as a backend?

Comment: Hello @Trex: I am using MongoDB

Comment: mongodb is not a relational database. use `belongs_to(species)`.
`http://www.chicagoboss.org/api-record.html`

Answer (score 3):

**model:** anatomy.erl

```
-module(anatomy, [Id,
             UID,
             Name,
             Property,
             Ratio::float(),
             Value::integer(),
             Pieces::float(),
             Status]).
-has({species,many}).
-compile(export_all).
```

**model:** species.erl

```
-module(species, [Id,
             UID,
             Name,
             Property,
             AnatomyId,
             Morphology   
             Gender]).
-belongs_to(anatomy).
-compile(export_all).
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure that I understand your question, so forgive me if this is a waste of your time. But... I think you need to rename the property in the anatomy.erl to AnatomyId and then make use of the -belongs and -has associations:

```
module(species, [Id,
                 UID,
                 Name,
                 Property,
                 AnatomyId,
                 Morphology   
                 Gender]).
-compile(export_all).
-belongs_to(anatomy).
```

The -belongs_to(anatomy) will add a function, anatomy() which returns the BossRecord, of type anatomy, with the id = AnatomyId.

This will not create a relation in Mongo, but might give you the behavior you are looking for